# Making a SwiftUI view disappear

Tags: swiftui

Good day.

Is there a way to make a child view that is being called from the parent view disappear if, let's say, a bool condition is true? I want to make it completely disappear, not hidden via opacity, isHidden, etc.

I want to know if this is possible, thank you!

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Right now, I don't have any concrete code to show :) I just wanted to hypothetically know if such thing exists in SwiftUI because after my research on google, I was only able to find a way to hide a view, and not actually make it disappear. But the idea is that I want to make the ChildView() that I call in ContextView() disappear after a button click, and there's a bool condition that is being set to true when the button is clicked.

Comment: Ah ok, check my answer. That should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SwiftUI you can conditionally show a view like...

```
if someCondition {
  YourConditionalView()
}
```

This will only show that view if the `someCondition` is true.

From your comment...

```
struct YourView: View {
  @State var showView = true

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      if showView {
        Text("Hello there!")
      }

      Button {
        self.showView.toggle()
      } label: {
        Text("Press me")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This view will start with a label "Hello there!" and a button. When you tap the button the `showView` boolean is toggled. This will then cause the label to be added/removed from the view based on the value of `showView`.

Comment: Hmm, what I rather want is to hide a view that is already visible at the start. So when my app runs, the child view is visible, however when a user clicks on a button this view will disappear.

Comment: @lex updated with an example of how to use this.

Comment: This is perfect! Haha for some reason I didn't think of making the bool initially true and setting it to false/toggle when the button is clicked, I'll blame my beginner self for that. :D Thank you!